# cyassimp for trimesh in python anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda, shapely, trimesh

Attempting to follow [the instructions here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/trimesh), I type

```
conda install -n my-conda-env -c menpo/label/master cyassimp
```

I get

> ```
> Fetching package metadata .............
> Solving package specifications: 
> PackageNotFoundError: Dependency missing in current osx-64 channels: 
>   - cyassimp -> assimp 3.0.1270
>
> Close matches found; did you mean one of these?
>     assimp: cyassimp
> ```

I then try some guesses (not knowing much about conda install), partly driven by results, which are all negative:

```
conda install -n my-conda-env -c menpo/label/master assimp
conda install -n my-conda-env -c menpo/label/master assimp 3.0.1270
conda install -n my-conda-env -c menpo/label/master assimp-3.0.1270
conda install -n my-conda-env -c menpo/label/master assimp_3.0.1270
conda install -n my-conda-env -c menpo/label/master assimp cyassimp
conda install -n my-conda-env -c menpo/label/master assimp: cyassimp
conda install -n my-conda-env -c menpo/label/master assimp:cyassimp
conda install -n my-conda-env -c menpo/label/master assimp::cyassimp
```

etc. etc.

Some googling and trawling in forums for `assimp` and `cyassimp` also did not yield useful clues.

Other steps in the instructions did succeed, namely

```
conda install -n my-conda-env -c conda-forge rtree shapely
```

so I am hopeful that the library exists, and that I just don't know how to name it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [at this page on the anaconda site](https://anaconda.org/menpo/cyassimp), referred there by [mikedh, the author and keeper of trimesh at github](https://github.com/mikedh). That page is only easy to find if you type "cyassimp" in to "Search Anaconda Cloud." I did not do that at first because I didn't know I wanted to search the Anaconda cloud (whatever that is), I thought I wanted to search the Anaconda web site.